# EF Core Linq expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with an EF Core query when I'm filtering against a nullable Guid property, for example

```
public class Order 
{
  public Guid? MachineId {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to filter orders based on a list of `MachineId`s

```
var machineIds // a list of Guids

var orders = _context.Orders.Where(x => machineIds.Contains(x.MachineId.GetValueOrDefault()));
```

The error I'm getting is

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Orders>
        .Where(x => __machineIds_0
            .Contains(m.MachineId.GetValueOrDefault()))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I'm not sure how to express this query another way - can anyone help?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you remove `.GetValueOrDefault()` and make `machineIds` a list of nullable guids (rather than guids)?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I suggest you open a bug report with a minimal repro case here. They should be able to help you at the efcore github - or at least take that as a bug. This looks really like it SHOULD work - but obviously it does not, which is a hole in the LINQ translation (one among MANY). Opening a bug report helps them to slowly solve them.

Comment: @mjwills that worked - thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest removing the use of `.GetValueOrDefault()` and make machineIds a list of nullable guids (rather than guids).

This might look like:

```
var machineIds = new List<Guid?>();

var orders = _context.Orders.Where(x => machineIds.Contains(x.MachineId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting the list of Guids to a list of nullable Guids resolves the issue (thanks [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills)).

```
var machineIds = machines
  .Select(x =>  new Guid?(x.Id));
```

The EF Core query becomes

```
var orders = _context.Orders.Where(x => machineIds.Contains(x.MachineId));
```

Comment: I hope to God you are not ending up with client side evaluation for that.

Comment: Even if this fixes it, looks like you are hitting a bug (the same code works for nullable int for instance), so it will be good to be reported to their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev bug report raised here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22243

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
_context.Orders.Where(order => MachineIds.Where(Id => Id == order.MachineId).Any())
```

This is untested. Modifications might be necessary.